# Horror movie of the 70s: WW2 German undead supersoldiers rise from ocean

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

This one is easy as the movie is renowned in its genre but the title escapes my memory.

I'm looking for a **horror movie of the 70s, probably Italian, certainly European**: a group of people, probably castaways, are **on a deserted tropical island**.

Troubles start when **the wreck of a ship surfaces: it held the corpses of WW2 German soldiers who had been reanimated through superscientific means and turned into unkillable killing machines.**
They all wore desert glasses implanted and tearing those away was the only way to kill them.
I seem to remember that all the characters die, as it needs to be in a proper horror movie.

An emblematic scene is when these undead supersoldiers come to life: you see the calm, flat surface of the ocean, the ship's wreck in the background and then all of a sudden several soldiers emerge, as though they were lying down under the water and then bent over their upper bodies 90°.

I've seen this movie several times on TV in the 80s and 90s, then I gave up on TV and haven't seen it anymore I also used to remember the title but now I've forgot it.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds a lot like [*Shock Waves*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076704/) from 1977.  It is set on an island and has Nazi Zombies.  I remember the scene you mentioned about the soldiers lying supine in the water, then rising up.

> Visitors to a remote island discover that a reclusive Nazi commandant has been breeding a group of Zombie soldiers.

**Movie Poster**
[image: Movies Poster showing the glasses]

### Trailer

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you for your help! Looks like I was wrong: it's an American movie, not European as I thought.

Comment: And the Wikipedia article at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_Waves_(film) mentions killing them by pulling off their goggles.

Comment: @ZabZonk. Great to hear this is the film  you were seeking.  Glad I was able to help.